# Select rows based on dynamic conditions

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I aim to select the rows corresponding to criteria in inputboxes, copy it, and paste it to another worksheet.

The code works but I need to fill all the inputboxes to copy paste the desired rows.

I would like if I do not fill one inputbox, still return all the rows matching  the other criteria (example: if just fill the "Issue" InputBox it returns the rows with the matching issue date).

```
Sub filter()

Dim Bookrunner As String
Dim Bond_Type As Variant
Dim Currency_st As String
Dim Year_Issue As Integer

Bond_Type = InputBox("Choose a Bond Type", "Bond Type")
Currency_st = InputBox("Choose a Currency", "Currency")
Year_Issue = InputBox("Chosse the Year of Issuance", "Issue")
Bookrunner = InputBox("Choose a Bookrunner", "Bookrunner")

Dim copyFrom As Range
Dim i As Long

With Feuil1
    For i = 2 To 54
        If .Range("B" & i) = Bond_Type And _
        .Range("K" & i) = Currency_st And _
        .Range("D" & i).Value = Year_Issue And _
        (.Range("R" & i) = Bookrunner Or .Range("S" & i) = Bookrunner Or _
          .Range("T" & i) = Bookrunner Or .Range("U" & i) = Bookrunner Or _
          .Range("V" & i) = Bookrunner Or .Range("w" & i) = Bookrunner) Then
            If copyFrom Is Nothing Then
                Set copyFrom = .Range("B" & i)
            Else
                Set copyFrom = Union(.Range("B" & i), copyFrom)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With

If Not copyFrom Is Nothing Then copyFrom.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Feuil2").Range("A2")

End Sub
```

Comment: One way might be to add some ORs , e.g. `If (.Range("B" & i) = Bond_Type OR Bond_Type=vbnullstring) And ...` ? I think my logic is correct, but do check.

Comment: Great ! Thank you so much. It works for all the string but for the Issue Date which is a number is does not work, I've tried to replace vbnullstring by "" but it is still not compatible. Any insight on this? Thank you

Comment: If it's declared as an Integer try `=0`.

Comment: it works, it's all good. Thank you very much !